# Azure data factory rest api x-ms-file-rename-source issues

Tags: rest, azure-data-factory

I have a pipeline in Azure Data Factory that is using a web task to rename a file on a file share on one of our azure storage accounts using rest api.

The process almost works and creates a copy of the file with the new name, but the new file is empty. I’ve tried this with both xlsx and a standard txt file. These are the headers I’m using:

```
x-ms-date: <generating in ADF>  
x-ms-version: 2021-08-06  
x-ms-rename-source: <path to original file>  
x-ms-type: file  
x-ms-content-length: <?>
```

I put <?> for content length because I think this is the issue and I’m not sure what value I should use here. I tried not including the x-ms-content-length to preserve the file attributes but I get an error that the header is required. Any thoughts on why the file is empty/being resized?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which REST API call you're using but it ***might*** not be the correct one? You need to use 'path create' if not already, see this link to the Microsoft docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/datalakestoragegen2/path/create)

For this API call you only 'technically' need the `x-ms-rename-source` header, although its probably a good idea to add the `x-ms-version` but it does work without this. I've written a blog post on how to do this in ADF [here](https://aventius.co.uk/blog/) with screen shots and pipeline parameters if you need a bit more

The ADF web request settings should be like this:-

**URL** = this is the ***full*** url of the ***new*** file in the data lake, ***NOT*** the location of the current existing file! For example, something like `https://yourstorageaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/name-of-container/somefolder/anotherfolder/the-new-file-name-here.csv`

**Method** = this is the web method for the request, we need to use `PUT`

**Body** = this particular API request does not require a body, however data factory complains about an empty body so we need to use a workaround. Click the 'add dynamic content' under the Body value and set the expression to be `@toLower('')` then this will produce an empty body and stop data factory complaining

**Authentication** = set this to use the 'System Assigned Managed Identity' as the this will make the web request to the API as the data factory's own managed identity (make sure you've added permissions for the data factory's account on the datalake!). This way we don't need to worry about getting or setting tokens and all that jazz

**Resource** = set this to `https://storage.azure.com`

**Headers** = we can get away with just a single header here, the `x-ms-rename-source` header. This is the folder location of the ***existing*** file. It doesn't want the protocol or DNS, but it does need the container name. So it might something like `/container-name/folder1/folder2/existing-file-name.csv`

Hope that helps